# Moving from CursorAdapter to an Endless adapter implementation

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter, cwac-endless

I am developing an app for Android Api 15 and above.

I have been using a custom `CursorAdapter` implementation with a `ListView` for some time now. I was under the impression that even with many thousands of rows (records) the `ListView` would handle the performance side of things.

My phone, a Sony Xperia U, has a hard time scrolling beyond 10 - 20 rows. The first few rows scroll nicely and then I hit a wall of stuttering and the device becoming unresponsive (A total of 70 rows all together). It is running Android 4.0.4. Other phones such as the Samsung S3 and Sony Xperia Z perform much better, but at what point is this going to degrade. These 2 phones are running 4.1. I am getting the `CursorWindow` warning seen below on the Xperia U.

I have implemented all the tricks in the trade, `ViewHolder` pattern etc, and all images are loaded inside `AsyncTask`'s.

Anyway, the trouble I am having regarding performance does not lie inside the `BindView`. The `BindView` method completes quite quickly - within 1-3 milliseconds.

The problem I believe lies with the `CursorWindow`. I really don't even know what this is!

```
08-14 21:01:58.913: W/CursorWindow(7116): Window is full: requested allocation 277981 bytes, free space 148792 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
```

I also read there is an issue in `CursorWindow` up to potentially 4.2 but this could be false:

> http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=4993

When it comes to the data for each row, I have an `SQLite` `blob`:

```
byte[] avatar = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(Profile.TABLE_COLUMN_AVATAR));
```

I think this might be one of the issues, but I am uncertain. I probably should switch the image/s to an SD card and store the path in the DB instead. I would like to keep my current setup though.

This then suggests that my current approach is not going to be manageable and hence a new approach might be necessary. So this gets me thinking about an Endless Adapter solution which would mean getting the cursor data with a limit/offset and filling up an `ArrayAdapter` and using a framework like CommonWare's `EndlessAdapter` (perhaps)?

1. Does my performance problem lie less with the `CursorAdapter` and more with the use of `Blob`s?
2. Should I be using an Endless Adapter approach with potentially large data sets?
3. Is CommonWare's `EndlessAdapter` still a good solution after 4 years?

Comment: It's very likely something to do with your blob is a major source of your issues. There's an easy way to check. Comment it out (and related relevant code) and try. Keep in mind that either way, your image loading should not be on the main thread and you should be doing it asynchronously.

Comment: @kabuko Yes I have read that it might be. I have commented out all the code except a little text (`TextView`). I still get the unresponsive stuttering after 10 - 20 rows especially when scrolling up. The Cursor with the blob is still being created and passed to `bindView` even though I am not using it - could this CursorWindow be the culprit?

Comment: @kabuko I will now modify my query to request all fields except the avatar blob field and see if this improves performance.

Comment: @kabuko Oh my God - leagues better. Seems the `Blob` is the problem, it is exausting the CursorWindow. No `Blob`s no Probs!

Comment: Yeah, as I suspected. Something like 70 rows should be no problem at all normally. Just load the blob asynchronously.

Comment: @kabuko Yes, from a file not form the cursor. The cursor `Blob` is the prob. So i will need to store a path in the DB instead. Well, that sucks a little!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does my performance problem lie less with the CursorAdapter and more with the use of Blobs?

Use Traceview to determine exactly where your problem lies. In the future, you might also consider being a lot more specific in your question, as we have no idea what a "hard time" means.

> Should I be using an Endless Adapter approach with potentially large data sets?

If your "hard time" is in initially loading the data out of your database, perhaps, though somebody out there may have an endless-list solution that will work OK with a set of `CursorAdapters`.

If your "hard time" is in scrolling the results, then no, `EndlessAdapter` or equivalents will not help you.

> Is CommonWare's EndlessAdapter still a good solution after 4 years?

For its use case, sure. Then again, I'm biased. :-)

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I updated my question for clarity regarding "hard time". Could this `CursorWindow` warning be the culprit?

Comment: Most interesting re: scrolling the results. BindView is not an issue so it might have something to do with the cursor data exausting the CursorWindow...

Comment: @Haraldo: You are welcome to still hold your... ummm... whatever data in the BLOBs rather than files, if you want. As kabuko indicated, load those asynchronously, in separate `rawQuery()` calls. If those are images, put up a placeholder image initially, then pop in the decoded BLOB later on. One benefit of going with files is that Picasso (http://square.github.io/picasso/) and similar libraries make the decode-and-replace-the-placeholder pattern easy.

Comment: Ahhh, I see. Execute a query inside the adapter in BindView? Genius.

Comment: @Haraldo: I'd phrase it more as "kick off an `AsyncTask` in `bindView()`".